# xinetd: is it possible to bind service to all interfaces EXCEPT one?

Tags: xinetd

I have previously asked this on ServerFault, but since it seems to get little views there, maybe there's a chance it will be better answered here... (I have deleted the post in ServerFault as indicated in the comments).

I have a service that is running under xinetd. My server has many network interfaces, one of them is connected to external network and all others are connected to multiple internal networks.

I want the service to be available to all internal networks, but not to the external one. Is it possible to do it in `xinetd.conf` file somehow? The "bind" option seems to do exactly the opposite: bind service to one particular interface, but not to the others. I cannot list all the interfaces (except one) explicitly in the config file, as the interfaces themselves and their IPs can change (most of them are VLAN interfaces that are added/removed on the fly).

Or is the only method to firewall out the service on external interface with iptables or similar?

Comment: You should delete the [question in serverfault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Cross-posting is [not accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) in SE sites.

Comment: OK, I have deleted the post in ServerFault as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I just now came across the only_from setting in xinetd.conf, that may
do what you want. (Or maybe not: you do not seem to know the IPs of
your internal interfaces.)
Suppose the external interface is 129.78.68.1, and the internal ones are 10.18.1.2 and 10.19.2.3 (with maybe varying IPs or varying number of interfaces) so all internal machines have IPs of 10.x.y.z, then the option
only_from=10.0.0.0
may do what is wanted. Please see https://linux.die.net/man/5/xinetd.conf or maybe https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/xinetd-primer/ for documentation.

Comment: I’m not familiar with it, but, by its name, “only_from” sounds like the *opposite* of what the question is asking for.  Can you (1) give an example of how (you think) it can be used to solve this problem. (2) link to documentation. and (3) explain why you believe that it will work.

Comment: OP wants to bind to all interfaces except the one external; does not know the (names or) IPs of the various internal interfaces. Maybe (hopefully!) he knows the IP ranges of all possible internal networks: list these on the only_from line. This would then accept from any internal IPs only, in other words not from external networks: thus not from the external interface, as desired.

Comment: The OP says “I cannot list all the interfaces (except one) …, as the interfaces themselves and their IPs can change ….” Are you saying that the solution is to use “only_from” with range(s) that cover all possible internal networks? If so, then please [edit] your answer to ***say** so*.  And, I repeat, a link to documentation would be great.